# How to listen for messages from SQS in nodesJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to use SQS the same way we used RabbitMQ or Kafka where we set up a listener.

But I dont see a way to setup a listener for SQS anywhere in their docs:

*I am able to receive to message(s) like*:

```js
 const client = new SQSClient({
    region: 'ap-south-1',
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY!,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY!,
    },
  })

  const command = new ReceiveMessageCommand({ QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_URL! }) 
  const data = await client.send(command)
  console.log(data) //  here
```

But this is one time, how can I set up an active listener, which either:

- continously listens (which I doubt SQS provides)
- or keeps checking for new messages in some interval function

Thanks, would love the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the same issue and came across this npm package
[sqs-consumer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqs-consumer).

According to the documentation: " ...
• The queue is polled continuously for messages using long polling.
..."